# set zend framework action controller

Tags: zend-framework, controller, action, router

i want to set my action controller from within a hidden filed in my view script form and when my form submitted zend framework router diagnose the action.
like this:

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a HTML form. The easiest way would be to do a [_forward()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Controller/Zend_Controller_Action.html#_forward) using the values you got from the form inside the the controller/action the form submits to.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
$action = $this->_getParam('action', 'default-action-name');

return $this->_forward($action); //assumes same controller and module
```